# Cannot find table in geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, query, personal-geodatabase, data-management

I was using the Make Query Table tool in ArcGIS. Once the tool finishes running, the result (a table whose name I specify) is automatically added to the Table of Contents and I can view the data contained within. The source info shows that it's supposed to be stored inside of the geodatabase from which one of the tool's inputs was selected. However, I cannot find the table in the geodatabase. How can I locate this table?

Comment: Did you do a Refresh in ArcCatalog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should verify the source of the table - this will make sure it's not somewhere that you don't expect or intend.

Do this by opening the properties window for the table and going to the 'Source' tab.  Make sure that the table ended up in the place you're looking.

If you can verify the source but still can't see it in the database - try refreshing your display of the database contents - either press F5 (with the database selected) or right-clicking and choosing "Refresh".

EDIT -

After looking at the [ESRI documentation](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Make_Query_Table_(Data_Management)) for the tool it seems that the layer is indeed temporary.  A new table is not created.

Comment: Thank you. As stated in my post, I did check the source and it pointed to the geodatabase. I also refreshed it and restarted several times and still no table. However, I am beginning to think that the tool (Make Query Table) may actually not create a table (though it looks like one), but rather store query results accessing data from another input table. Maybe I have to export the final results to another table?

Comment: "The layer that is created by the tool is temporary and will not persist after the session ends unless the document is saved."  From the ESRI help on the tool.

Comment: That is the issue. I just exported the results to another table and the problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: That's just what I was going to say - good work.